# plugin function is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript

i am using list scroll er jquery plugin [Link](http://als.musings.it/#demo)
[Link](http://als.musings.it/#demo)

added js and css file in index.html

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.als-1.7.js"></script>
```

declare var in `typings.d.ts` file

```
declare var als:any;
declare let $itemsize:any;
```

app.component.ts file

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $("#lista1").als({
                    visible_items: 4,
                    scrolling_items: 2,
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    circular: "yes",
                    autoscroll: "no",
                    interval: 5000,
                    speed: 500,
                    easing: "linear",
                    direction: "right",
                    start_from: 0
                });
  }
```

error
$itemsize is not defined

Comment: jQuery is added?

Comment: jQuery already added  declare var $ : any;

Comment: i.e jquery.js in your index.html & its sequence ..i.e first it is loaded then the library

Comment: like that sequence included